# JavaScript parsing a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, file

I am using the following code to parse a single line of a JSON file:

```
var str = '{ "jobID": "2598752", "account": "TG-CCR120014", "user": "charngda",
   "pkgT": {"mvapich2-new/1.2": { "libA": ["libmpich.so.1.1"], "flavor": ["default:pgi/7.2-5"] } },
   "startEpoch": "1338608868", "runTime": "48", "execType": "user:binary", "exec": "IOR", 
   "numNodes": "4", "sha1": "755187bd8550881bb0c9951822e74a9a53c8d0f3", "execEpoch": 1336757832, 
   "execModify": "Fr, Ma, 1, 12:37:1, 2012", "startTime": "Fr, Ju,  , 22:47:4, 2012",
   "numCores":  "64","sizeT": { "bss": "36224", "text": "3502656", "data": "128944" } }';
 var obj = JSON.parse(str);
 delete obj['flavor'];
 delete obj['pkgT'];
 var newstr = JSON.stringify(obj);
 document.write(str);
```

However, I want to parse the entire 6000 line JSON file.  How do i read the file line by line and delete the fields as I have done with the single line.  I have zero experience with Javascript so I have no clue how to read a file or create a new file.  I assume I would use some sort of array, but I am not sure.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Javascript doesn't really use files...unless you are using Node or something similar. Can you give more detail?

Comment: Ok I have a very large JSON file that each line is formatted as the str variable above.  Ultimately, I want to create a new file where each line contains only the jobID and exec fields.  I really don't care how I accomplish this, but I have asked numerous questions on here and this Javascript is the closest I've gotten to a solution.  If you have a better idea please share.

Comment: Just create a object with jobID and exec as properties .. Extract those fields from your JSON file and assign to the new object created

Comment: @amber4478 Do you need to do this on a website, or just on your local machine? As if you only need to do this locally a short script you run from the terminal would be much better suited to this (can be Node (Javascript))

Comment: Sorry for the late responses I have been at work all day, but I am not running this on a website.  What I am planning to do is for each JobID put the co-occurring exec files in a DSM and then do some analysis.  But I have daily logs that are about 6000 lines for an entire year that need parsed.

Answer (score 0):

If your file looks like this:

```
[{"jobID": "1",...},{"jobID": "2",...},{"jobID": "3",...},...]
```

You can do something like this:

```
var objArray = JSON.parse(str);

 for( var k=0; k<objArray.length; k++ ) {

 delete objArray[k]['flavor'];
 delete objArray[k]['pkgT'];

  }
var newstr = JSON.stringify(objArray);
document.write(newstr);
```

Just add the complete file content to the str variable by copy and paste.

**This solution won't help you if you need to do this on a regular basis !**

Comment: Once I format all of them I  won't need to mess with them again so I will try this out.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work. I haven't got a 6000 line JSON file to test it on, but it should at the least give you a clear idea where you should be going next with your solution.

Remember, JSON blocks are just ordinary javascript objects which are a data structure already with their own methods, so you can iterate over them by just using standard object iteration.

```
var bigObj = json.parse(jsonFile);
var objArray = [];
var newStr;
for (var obj in bigObj){
    if (bigObj.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
    delete obj['flavor'];
    delete obj['pkgT'];
    newStr = JSON.stringify(obj);
    objArray.push(newStr);
    }
}
document.write(objArray.join("/n").toString());
```